# The cursor SQL_CURLH200C1 is not in a prepared state

Tags: sql, db2

Can anyone provide an explanation for the following:

```
select * from 'table' as t where t.identifier = 1234567890
```

Returns: 
THE SQL STATEMENT IS NOT SUPPORTED. SQLCODE=-142, SQLSTATE=42612

---

```
select * from 'table' as t where t.identifier = 12345
```

Returns:
1 row(s)

---

Identifier is defined as PIC S9(11)      COMP-3, DB2

Comment: Does it work with 123456789, 12345678 or 1234567?

Comment: And where does a cursor enter into this?  I just see a regular `SELECT` statement.  And _please_ don't name your tables (or columns) after keywords (or use spaces).  The SQLSTATE message implies that the statement is not valid in that context - is there anything else going on around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'table'` is a string literal with the value `table` therefor it cannot be used as a table name.

If your table is really called table, then you need to use this:

select * from "TABLE"

or

select * from "table"

depending on how you created that table named table.